# relating tables with the ORM prism

Tags: database, postgresql, orm, foreign-keys, prisma

Using PostgreSQL, I want to make an application that manages Daily Habits. I'm trying to make a one-to-many relationship from the User tables to Habits and Habits to the other tables.

```
model User {
  id           String   @id @default(uuid())
  email        String   @unique
  verify_email Boolean  @default(false)
  Habit        Habit?   @relation(fields: [habitId], references: [id])
  habitId      String[] @unique

  @@index([habitId])
  @@map("user")
}

model Habit {
  id         String          @id @default(uuid())
  title      String
  created_at DateTime
  user       User[]
  dayHabits  DayHabit[]
  weekDays   HabitWeekDays[]

  @@map("habits")
}
```

Creating habits, when there is more than one Habit, the new one overwrites the previous one.

[rest of code](https://github.com/higordevv/server-habit/blob/main/prisma/schema.prisma)

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help] Please do not **yell**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating one-to-many relations in Prisma is pretty straightforward as can be seen in the [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/one-to-many-relations)

An example code of one-to-many relation between user and habit is

```js
model User {
  id           String   @id @default(uuid())
  email        String   @unique
  verify_email Boolean  @default(false)
  habit        Habit[]   
  @@index([id])
  @@map("user")
}

model Habit {
  id         String          @id @default(uuid())
  title      String
  created_at DateTime
  user       User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId      String
  // dayHabits  DayHabit[]
 // weekDays   HabitWeekDays[]

  @@map("habits")
}
```

Also, you didn't specify what you are trying to achieve with these fields `dayHabits` and `weekDays`.